# How to adjust the Brightness , contrast of an image?

Tags: image-processing

How to adjust the Brightness , contrast of  an image?

- how to adjust the image brightness  Normally for ex: it ranges from -255 to 255.

Now I want to increase the brightness by +100.
By using the below formula I could able to find the brightness of an image, but how to adjust/change

```
Brightness = (0.2126*nRed) + (0.7152*nGreen) + (0.0722*nBlue);
```

---

How should I approach further to achieve this?

Comment: in what? Photoshop, any programming language, anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have your image as an array of pixel values (usually 0-255 in each of Red, Green and Blue), you could apply a simple scaling to each channel of each pixel in turn and see if this worked well enough. Be careful, you must be sure to catch overflowing values and clamp them to the highest possible brightness (and perhaps underflowing to lowest brightness as well, depending on how your pixels are represented).

Comment: In C++ , so will it do - For 100,if i add 100 to each R G B pixels . If i get OVerflow i will fix the RGB  planes to 255 and the under flow let me fix it to the Zero.. will it do ..by adding 100 n reducing 100 in image

Comment: I think you'll get better results by multiplying (say) by 1.15 to give a 15% brightness boost.